# Javascript OOP, how to add an employee image to generated content

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

The layout is simple. I have buttons with employee names and a paragraph element.

When clicking on the name, a function generates data from a constructor.

That constructor has a prototype method 'out'.

Now I would like to append an image to the generated content, but I can't figure out how.

The function looks like this:

```
person.prototype.out = function(target){
var whenHidden = function () {
target.textContent = this.firstName + ' '+ this.lastName +" is aged " + this.age + 
                         " this employees salary is " + this.salary ;
target.removeEventListener('transitionend', whenHidden);
target.classList.remove('hide');
/*
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/young-female-   employee-14787651.jpg");
elem.setAttribute("height", "40");
elem.setAttribute("width", "50");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "employee");
demo.appendChild(elem);
*/
}.bind(this);
target.addEventListener('transitionend', whenHidden);
target.classList.add('hide');
};
```

This commented out code, in the pen its JS lines 17-22 is causing trouble.

If I remove it, I get the proper text to the paragraph, if I run it as is, only the image shows, and the text does not. Obviously, I would like to have both text and the image there.

I know, this solution is no good for if I wanna have a pic per employee, I would kindly appreciate any suggestions on how to do that.

On a side note, I have that input field and the search button, the idea is to type the employees first name to the input field, click the button and then have the info from the constructor function and the image generated into the paragraph. That function looks so wrong to me, I know, but it gives no error.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/pRzQoB

Ok a little update:

The text was there, just hidden, sorry for that.
Now what still remains is how to best implement to have an image for every employee, as the current version is only good for one employee(tried as example).
And why does the search through the input field not work?(The button with the names is kind of a pure training "solution").

Comment: What is `demo`, it's not defined anywhere. What errors are thrown in browser console? Also shouldn't have spaces in url for image. A [mcve] would help

Comment: There are no spaces in the URL. No errors in console, the text was there all along, it was just hideen because of padding issues, the image pushed the text down. demo is defined on line 34, its just the paragraph where the content goes into.

Comment: @charlietfl
Sorry forgot to add the codepen link, its there now:-)
Btw, I think the spaes in the code for the image are me not being familiar with how to enter code here, it's fine on the pen.Phew, all confusion is cleared now I think:-)

Comment: @ptts, you should add image link to your person function, and update your objects accordingly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjNaNy P.S. Didn't updated images for the rest, except andrea, but you will understand, i am sure.

Comment: @sinisake
AyeAye, got it, thanks, that is a very elegant solution:-)
Mind checking why that code on line 50-60does not work? It's really bugging me:-)

Comment: @ptts, not sure, to be honest, really, some problem with anonymus function you use...but if i could suggest different approach: https://jsfiddle.net/hxmwo6bf/

Comment: @sinisake
That is great,Ihave afew questions about it, I struggle to understand the following:
I see you did not use bind anymore, but instead this:
out(person[this.textContent.toLowerCase()], << this is your first parameter for the out fn.Where does this take the name from?From the button or from the person object?The this refers to the object, I know, but the textContent is confusing me.
I will post the next question in the next comment, to keep it readable:-)

Comment: @sinisake
The next thing is this part:
if(Object.keys(person).indexOf(entry.value.toLowerCase())!==-1) {
key=entry.value.toLowerCase();
out(person[key],demo);
The if statement checks if there is an object with the key of a persons name, right? If yes, the string is converted to lowerCase and stored in the key var. And then we call out() with the first parameter being person and the value of what is in key?  I have never fimiliarized with accessing objects with bracket notation, I agree this solution seems superior to what I had before. BTw, post this as anwser, it's very good.:-)

Comment: Yes, no binding - easier for me :), though, you can keep it your way - but, then there would be problems with calling - my suggestion is just for easier calling of out() function. 'this' in first question reffers to button, not person object, textContent is just element text... So, 'Andrea' - will became 'andrea'...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132187/discussion-between-ptts-and-sinisake).